# Bluemix : API Management - error "Swagger jsonReference". This is not supported. How do I fix it?

Tags: ibm-cloud, swagger, ibm-api-management

I've tried to import swagger document in json format. I got the error

> The field paths["/namespaces"].get.responses["401"] uses a Swagger
>   jsonReference. This is not supported. Remove this field, or in-line
>   the referenced JSON instead, and resubmit the request.

(I also attached the screenshot for just incase). The code snippet which might caused the error is like this:

```
"401": {
    "$ref": "#/responses/UnauthorizedRequest"
},
"500": {
    "$ref": "#/responses/ServerError"
}
```

What's wrong with this contents ?  Appreciate if you could point me how to fix the problem.

Thanks !

Ref: screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error looks like a limitation/bug but as the error description suggests, you can in-line the definition to get around it. Here is an example of inlining references in a Swagger document.

The following Swagger document has a `$ref`

```
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "Task retrieved",
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Task"
        }
    },
    "404": {
        "description": "Task not found"
    }
}

...

"definitions": {
    "Task": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "deadline",
            "description",
            "status"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "description": {
                "type": "string",
                "example": "Make an app for Demo"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string",
                "example": "Created"
            },
            "deadline": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date",
                "example": "01/15/16"
            }
        }
    }
```

After inlining the `$ref` definition, the Swagger document would look like this:

```
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "description": "Task retrieved",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
              "deadline",
              "description",
              "status"
          ],
          "properties": {
              "description": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "example": "Make an app for Demo"
              },
              "status": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "example": "Created"
              },
              "deadline": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "date",
                  "example": "01/15/16"
              }
          }
        }
    },
    "404": {
        "description": "Task not found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: I would consider a full import of a OpenAPI compliant specification a normal "feature". I know this might be seen as a "convenience feature", but manually "optimizing" a swagger specification just for the purpose of an import within an API Mgmt platform might not be acceptable in certain customer scenarios.
An OpenAPI specification file should be universally valid for all common API use-cases like for example documentation, client-stub generation, server-stub generation and of course API management.
I'll open an RFE for this "feature".